# Show Dropdown Menu Item if Current page is Its Child

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project on wordpress and making a main menu where all dropdown items are showing normally without hovering on it. I have hide all dropdown column at home page now I want to display specific dropdown if current page is its child item or main item. For example.

```
<ul class="menu">

<li class="menu-item">Page 1
<ul class="sub-menu active">
<li class="menu-item current_page_item">Page 1 Child A</li> 
<li class="menu-item">Page 1 Child B</li> 
<li class="menu-item">Page 1 Child C</li> 
</ul>
</li> 

<li class="menu-item">Page 2
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item">Page 2 Child A</li> 
<li class="menu-item">Page 2 Child B</li> 
<li class="menu-item">Page 2 Child C</li> 
</ul>
</li> 

<li class="menu-item">Page 3
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item">Page 3 Child A</li> 
<li class="menu-item">Page 3 Child B</li> 
<li class="menu-item">Page 3 Child C</li> 
</ul>
</li> 

</ul>
```

Now I want to show just Page 1 dropdown and if user goes to Page 2  (or then Page 2 Child A/B/C) then hide Page 1 dropdown and show Page 2 dropdown.

Please let me know if how can I do this by CSS or Javascript. CSS will be easy for me.

Thanks

Comment: Need to know what is in url to know which page is which and how it matches with the dropdown list. Should be able to do this in your wordpress template also instead of waiting for javascript to do it client side

Comment: set `.sub-menu{display:none}` when the user is on page 2 set `active` class to `.menu-item` like this `.menu-item.active .sub-menu{display:block}`, this way it will show only the active page dropdown.

Comment: URL is just like /page-3, well I am show dropdown as horizontally and I didn't find the option in my theme.

Comment: I cannot add .active class if any of its child item is active.

Comment: Get the name of your page with `window.location.pathname` That might include the folder(s) your page it located in, but you can check if the string in your `li.menu-item` is found in your `pathname`. Hopefully no page name are duplicated. Just an idea.

Comment: Yes I have found a Unique Class with sub-menu if current page is its child page and my problem has solved. Thanks for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution because after some struggle with lots of Classes and IDs I finally found a unique class with sub-menu so I hide all sub menu by

```
.menu-item ul
{
display: none;
}
```

After that I show active dropdown menu by

```
.menu-item .active {
display: block !important;
}
```

Thanks